# Nested MySQL syntax error trying to add division operator

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this that executes and works perfectly:

```
UPDATE users
SET player_skill = (
(
        SELECT
            sum(avg_score)
        FROM
            skill
        WHERE
            username = "JohnDoe"
        AND game = "Bingo"
    ) - 
    (
        SELECT
            sum(avg_score)
        FROM
            events
        WHERE
            game = "Bingo"
    ) 

) WHERE username = "JohnDoe"
```

I want to add a division operator like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET player_skill = (
    (
        (
            SELECT
                sum(avg_score)
            FROM
                skill
            WHERE
                username = "JohnDoe"
            AND game = "Bingo"
        ) - (
            SELECT
                sum(avg_score)
            FROM
                events
            WHERE
                game = "Bingo"
        )
    ) / SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        skill
    WHERE
        username = "JohnDoe"
    AND game = "Bingo"
)
WHERE
    username = "JohnDoe"
```

It spits out an error code at me

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*)
FROM
    skill
WHERE
    username = "JohnDoe"
AND game = "Bingo" )
) W' at line 21
```

I've tried for awhile but can't seem to figure out why it wont let it run. I have similar queries to this that seem fine but I cannot get this one to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You missed to wrap the last select within parentheses

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  UPDATE users
  SET player_skill = (
                     SELECT (sum(s.avg_score) - sum(e.avg_score))/COUNT(e.*)
                     FROM skill s 
                     INNER JOIN events e on s.game = e.game
                     WHERE e.username = "JohnDoe"
                     AND  e.username = "Bingo"
                     )
```

when you try this query you will get this error :

> [Err] 1064 - You have no error in your SQL syntax. you dont need to check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use no near anything .